# Getting a Route's Name in the Base Controller in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have the following routes in my *routes.php* file:

```
Route::post('add/car',
        ['as' => 'api.add.car', 'uses' => 'ApiAddController@car']);
Route::post('add/bus',
        ['as' => 'api.add.bus', 'uses' => 'ApiAddController@bus']);
```

My *ApiAddController* is created by extending a base API controller.  Something like:

```
class ApiAddController extends ApiController{

    // Implementation

}
```

I would like to make the endpoint names (in this case *add/car* and *add/bus*) available as a variable in the base *ApiController*.

Is this possible with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it with

```
echo Route::currentRouteName();
```

Have a look at the [API](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getName), `Route::getName();` could also be what you need.